# RSelenium concurrent users for multiple scenarios on Shiny

Tags: r, selenium, shiny, rselenium, rsdriver

I am  trying to do a charge test with RSelenium on my deployed Shiny application. Several users connect to the adress and do random tasks at the same time.

I have searched `doParallel` but the number of concurrent process is limited by numbers of core - 1.

I have tried the following command line to start N process in the background at the same time. A number is given as parameter to define browser's port. It is working until 3 process but over some process fail and are not always the same.

```
'start /b "P1" Rscript R/run_tests.R 1 &
start /b "P2" Rscript R/run_tests.R 2 &
start /b "P3" Rscript R/run_tests.R 3 &
start /b "P4" Rscript R/run_tests.R 4 &
start /b "P5" Rscript R/run_tests.R 5'
```

`run_tests` open a new web driver and navigate on the webpage.

A solution would be to ask several colleagues to run this code for 3 process but I would like to reach 20 users.

Answer on Windows will be more appreciated but Linux is not a problem. Do you know the proper way to do it with RSelenium ? Thanks a lot for any clue.

Comment: Not sure about Shiny but have you tried the selenium grid?

Comment: it is a solution but infortunately `R` langage is not supported. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with JMeter but it seems not appropriate for your case, as written [here](https://github.com/slopp/Load-Test).

> Shiny relies on Javascript to respond to user interactions and
>   communicate with R as opposed to RESTful HTTP calls. This means
>   standard load testing frameworks like JMeter do not accurately
>   simulate load.

Please have a look at the info for [shinyloadtest](https://rstudio.github.io/shinyloadtest/). I have not used it personally, but according to the documentation it can be installed under Windows and supports:

> - Record a typical user session for the app.
> - Replay the session in
>     parallel, simulating many simultaneous users accessing the app.
> - Analyze
>     the results of the load test and determine if the app performed well
>     enough.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `RSelenium` is a need as I have several senarios that are really different and I am doing screenshots with a RMarkdown to check that everything is okay with visual inspection and OCR to check for errors.Thanks a lot for these two clues.